# Samba domain controller provisioning error: Domain must not be equal to short host name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, docker

I am trying to provision **samba domain controller** (with active directory) on **docker** container based on ubuntu, when I try to this **realm: NOURELDIN.LOCAL** with **domain: NOURELDIN** it workts fine, but with **realm: DC1.NOURELDIN.LOCAL** with **domain: DC1**, I get the following *error* and I don't know why, (I always remove smb.conf before starting new provision and samba is completely fresh installed).

I don't understand exactly why I get that error, I appreciate any help to solve that.

```
root@dc1:~/samba-4.5.0# samba-tool domain provision --use-rfc2307 --interactive
Realm [NOURELDIN.LOCAL]: DC1.NOURELDIN.LOCAL
 Domain [DC1]:
 Server Role (dc, member, standalone) [dc]:
 DNS backend (SAMBA_INTERNAL, BIND9_FLATFILE, BIND9_DLZ, NONE) [SAMBA_INTERNAL]:
 DNS forwarder IP address (write 'none' to disable forwarding) [192.168.1.1]:
Administrator password:
Retype password:
You are not root or your system do not support xattr, using tdb backend for attributes.
not using extended attributes to store ACLs and other metadata. If you intend to use this provision in production, rerun the script as root on a system supporting xattrs.
ERROR(<class 'samba.provision.ProvisioningError'>): Provision failed - ProvisioningError: guess_names: Domain 'DC1' must not be equal to short host name 'DC1'!
  File "/usr/local/samba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/samba/netcmd/domain.py", line 461, in run
    nosync=ldap_backend_nosync, ldap_dryrun_mode=ldap_dryrun_mode)
  File "/usr/local/samba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 2028, in provision
    sitename=sitename, rootdn=rootdn, domain_names_forced=(samdb_fill == FILL_DRS))
  File "/usr/local/samba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 627, in guess_names
    raise ProvisioningError("guess_names: Domain '%s' must not be equal to short host name '%s'!" % (domain, netbiosname))
```

Comment: You are trying to use a domain name part [dc1].noureldin.local equal to the hostname (DC1). FQDN for host will be dc1.dc1.noureldin.local with a name conflict in windows naming schema.

Comment: before 1 second I have just noticed exactly what you have written, I will not delete the question, it could be useful for some one else, thank you very much!, sorry I cannot vote you up because of my low reputation, regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a domain name part [dc1].noureldin.local equal to the hostname (DC1). FQDN for host will be dc1.dc1.noureldin.local with a name conflict in windows naming schema.

Comment: I have just noticed that, thx